# Consultant Travel Fees

Tags: travel, billing, consultants

I do some consulting work and have been asked to travel to a customer site several times per year over the next few years.  I know the tier one consultants bill a percentage of the total contract value for "travel fees" but what is the typical amount and the high-low range?

Research indicates that between 11% - 15% is usually proposed but what is generally accepted by customers (yes, all customers are different)?

I will re-post this question in a different stack if there is a better place to put it.

Comment: Why would you now bill what it costs? Flights, hire car, hotel, time? Why would it b a percentage? That sounds weird to me,

Comment: Can you please clarify? Are these travel fees in addition to the expenses of travel (fares, lodging, ground transport, cleaning)? Or do you propose to charge a percentage fee to cover your personal payment of those expenses?

Answer (score 2):

This is variable, there is no normal fee. It depends on timeframes, how far, how much etc,. Some consultants charge the hours travelling (myself included) and take their travel expense out of that. Others charge the travel expenses separately.